# Do all browsers scale images proportionally when only width or height is given?

Tags: javascript, image, scaling, dimensions, dimension

I noticed that if I only specify one dimension of an image, either using the `width` and `height` attributes on the `img` tag or using CSS, the browser automatically scales the other dimension proportionally.

For example, if I have a 100x150 image, and I specify `width="50"` or `width:50px;`, the browser automatically sets the height to 75 pixels.

Does this does this behavior apply to all browsers? Can I omit one just to save time? I'm preloading images with JavaScript and inserting them dynamically, so I don't have to worry about the images affecting the layout while downloading.

Comment: If this question were about a programming language, the answer would be "undefined behavior" ;)  But yes, most browsers behave this way.  And yes, failing to specify height and width attributes in an img tag is *very* poor form ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is part of the [CSS2 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width):

> [...] if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', 'height' has some
>   other computed value, and the element does have an intrinsic ratio;
>   then the used value of 'width' is:
>
> ```
> (used height) * (intrinsic ratio)
> ```

Defined CSS width or height will scale them properly in any CSS2 compliant browser (I tested it in IE6 and above).

And I consider this a very useful feature. Assume I have a forum with `800px` width layout and I allow users to upload images. Setting posts' images to `max-width:790px` without a defined height (`height:auto` as per default) will automatically make them fit without breaking my layout while keeping the correct aspect ratio. Neat stuff. *Note: [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-width#Browser_compatibility) isn't supported in IE6.*

Obviously, the same applies if you define a CSS `height` having `width:auto`.

And here's a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7rtgW/) for testing.  Apparently, HTML attributes will also scale properly in virtually all browsers. But I do still recommend doing the element styling with CSS, for the consistency and keeping the markup clean. Styling should be done through CSS.